# Why am I receiving a warning for missing type arguments and type conversion?

Tags: java, list, netbeans, arraylist, warnings

My class is as following, and works fine, but NetBeans shows following warning on line 18, I am wondering what is that for?

**Code**

```
public class Users {

        private List<Long> grades;

        ...
        public String retrieveAllGrades(){

Line 18    this.grades = new ArrayList();

           ...
        }

        getters and setters
}
```

**Warning on line 18**

```
Found raw type: ArrayList
missing type arguments for generic class ArrayList<E> where E is a type-variable: E extends Object declared in class ArrayList

[unchecked] unchecked conversion
required: List<Long>
found: ArrayList
```

Comment: required: List<Long> / found: ArrayList , why you didn't try that?

Comment: try what? ArrayList<Long> ?

Comment: Yes, it gives you a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
this.grades = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

This is because you define grades as `List<Long>()` but initalize as `ArrayList()` (you need the long part)

Comment: what should be both longs ? Long or long ? capital L or lower l?

Comment: thanks whats the difference to have it Long or long?

Answer (score 0):

for newer JDK versions (tested with Java 7 and above), you don't need to implicitly state the type (in this case 'Long').
You can simply do:

```
this.grades = new ArrayList<>();
```